# PlayFramework and Search for a Farsi word in MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I'm trying to search for a Farsi Word in a MySQL Database. The Table has been filled correctly and I can see and search for words in that using MySQLWorkbench. I have even setup the [JDBC-Performance-Logger](https://github.com/sylvainlaurent/JDBC-Performance-Logger) and logged the generated statement and paste it in MySQLWorkbench and the record could be found successfully.

My Problem is only in PlayFramework using EBean which the String cannot be found and it returns an empty result every time.

here is my application.conf:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8"
db.default.useUnicode=true
db.default.characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

And this is the function which returns an empty result:

```
final String cityName = "تهران";

final List<City> cities = City.find.where().like("name", "%" + cityName + "%").findList();

//final List<City> cities = City.find.select("name").where().eq("name", cityName).findList();

return ok(toJson(cities));
```

it generates this SQL Statement (found using JDBC-Performance-Logger):

```
select t0.id c0, t0.name c1, t0.province c2 from city t0 where t0.name like 'تهران' /*setString*/ escape''
```

Is is possible at all to search for farsi characters in Play Framework at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing connection string to this has solved the Problem:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDatabase?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```